# Ambiguous const Function

Tags: c++, class, ambiguous

I'm using an api that has a class where the two following functions are defined:

```
Module *getParent() { return Parent; }
const Module *getParent() const { return Parent; }
```

When I try to call the const version of the function like so:

```
void Foo::bar(Function* F){
    const Module* parent = F->getParent();
}
```

The compiler tells me the function call is ambiguous.
Since I cannot change the function declarations, how do I specify in my call to the function which version of the function I want?

**Edit**: As requested the exact error is:

```
'getParent' is ambiguous Candidates are: llvm::Module * getParent() const llvm::Module * getParent()
```

This is the only error in the file.

Comment: What is the type of `F`?

Comment: These functions reside in the class Function, F is an instance of Function.

Comment: The problem is in code that you haven't shown.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: *"F is an instance of Function."* - What is *Function*? Since you are having difficulty calling a member of *Function* it would help to see the declaration of *Function*.

Comment: Here is the reference for the Function class. http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/GlobalValue_8h_source.html#l00132

Comment: If `F` is an _instance_ of `Function`, rather than  _pointer_ to a `Function` possibly with some `const`/`volatile` qualifications, the code should fail for other reasons...!

Comment: I've updated with a minimal version of the function. This really is just a problem of how do I specify to call the function with the const return type.

Comment: Edit to the link that I posted "this is the class that Function extends" where the declaration of the functions in question are declared.

Comment: The code is still not sufficient to reproduce the problem (not to mention that it actually need the llvm headers and a suitable build-setup). Since you seem to have one of those: what is the _exact_ error (make sure you also include the _first_ error).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with gcc. This may be specific to a particular compiler. Which one did you use?

Answer (score 1):

`F` is a pointer to an object of type `Function`. Since the object is not const, `F->getParent()` calls the non-const version of `getParent()`. If you really want to call the const version, either pass `F` as a pointer to `const Function` or convert the pointer into a pointer to const object: `const_cast<const Function*>(F)->getParent()` will call the const version of `getParent()`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - of course it's const cast! See? <g>

Comment: This still does not explain why compiler inform that call is ambiguous. From what you write that it should simply choose the non-const version.

Comment: @NO_NAME - that's right. Neither call is ambiguous. The code in the question does have an error, though, and calling the const version fixes it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: But why? I don't see an error in the code shown in the question.